# TFS2010 & VS2012 which SDK should be placed on the server?

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2012, sdk, installation

I have a WebService made in vs2012 on 3.5fwk which uses programatically dlls of TFS to make workItems.

The since I've been working on vs2012 TFS's dlls are version 11.0.0.0, and not 10.0.0.0 as if I would work on a vs2010.

Oddly It works, on a machine with vs2012 installed and without TFS2010 installed, even when adding the dlls couldn't be done while the WebService project was on 3.5fwk (I had to make it 4.5 to be able to find the assemblies, and after adding them change it back to 3.5).

There's only 1 Gb left on the server so I can't install the whole VS on the server (and if we don't talk about licencing, this problem would be over).

I need to install an SDK Package on the server then, but, which one?

*Framework 4.5 fwk?*

*TFS2010 sdk?*

*TFS2012 sdk?*

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to install:

- [Team Foundation Server 2012 Object Model](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f30e5cc7-036e-449c-a541-d522299445aa)
- .NET Framework 4.5

And optionally [Visual Studio 2012 update 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305) to bring the object model up to the latest version. This should only install the updated version of the object model.

Or recompile against the 2010 binaries and install:

- [Team Foundation Server 2010 Object Model SP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a37e19fb-3052-4fc9-bef7-4a4682069a75)